# Remove @NonCPS annotation using PipelineNodeGraphVisitor

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline that calls a method to collect build information something like this:

```
    @NonCPS
    List<Stage> getStage(rawBuild) {

        def visitor =  new PipelineNodeGraphVisitor(rawBuild)

        def stages = visitor.pipelineNodes.findAll{
            it.type == FlowNodeWrapper.NodeType.STAGE
        }

        List<Stage> stageInfo = [];

        for (stage in stages){
            if( stage.node.endNode ) {
                def startTime  = TimingAction.getStartTime( stage.node )
                def endTime    = TimingAction.getStartTime( stage.node.endNode )
                stageInfo.add(new Stage(stage.displayName, startTime, endTime));
            }
        }

        return stageInfo;
    }
```

This works fine . However is it possible to retain this functionality and remove @NonCPS annotation since pipeline has restricted using NonCPS annotations.

Comment: Without the `@NonCPS` annotation you cannot pass complex objects that don't implement `Serializable`. 
In your specific case, you return a list of `Stage` objects.
If you can modify your function to return e.g. a list of three-element lists that consist of `[stage.displayName, startTime, endTime]` — and create the list you need later — I think you might be able to get rid of the annotation.